# Product in a preorder

Tags: category-theory

Is the product of two objectos $a,b$ in a preorder category their infimum $a\wedge b$? 
I can't assume that their infimum exists, can I?

Comment: The notation $a \wedge b$ denotes the infimum, actually. And the product of $a$ and $b$ exists if and only if the infimum exists. Dually, the coproduct exists if and only if the supremum exists.

Comment: @JohnM: thanks for the comment.

Comment: @JohnMyers I edited the question, so now it looks correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the product of $a$ and $b$ is $a\land b$, if it exists; however, this is the *infimum*, not the supremum. As you suspect, it need not exist for arbitrary $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Barbra: You’re welcome.